# Heroku can't import settings, but my computer can do it normally?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm deploying a Django application with Heroku. I have to import `settings.py` to `wsgi.py`. However, whenever I run `WSGI.py` on my computer, it runs normally. But heroku can't import this file and I have no idea what's happening.

This is what shows up when I run `heroku logs --tail`:

`2021-10-07T03:57:47.989483+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings'`

This is the folder strucute:

[image]

This is `WSGI.py`:

```
import os
import sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

As I've said before, if I run `WSGI.py` alone on my computer, it works and it finds `settings.py` normally. But Heroku can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You should put it as

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', '<your_project_name>.settings')
```

See if that works

Comment: Hey, friend, your quotation is empty.

Comment: Oh, just saw your edit and I've tried that already. No success.

Comment: your settigs.py file is inside your main directory that is your project name. That is why your python can't find the model settings.py

Comment: But why don't I get an error if I try to run it directly?

Comment: are you deploying through github? If so can you just point me to it?

Comment: I'm deploying directly from my cmd to heroku.

Comment: The code you mentioned says `NO MODULE NAMED <your_project_name>` and imports nothing.

Comment: By the way, `settings.py` and `WSGI.py` are on the same folder, could this be the problem?

Comment: No, it should be in the same folder

Comment: If it's the same folder then why does it need `<your_project_name>` first?

Comment: I know it's obvious but I wanna confirm ```<your_project_name>``` is exactly ```ThronesAPI``` right?

Comment: That's correct. But it's important to say the main django project is also called `ThronesAPI`